# How to use tinyMCE with symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, tinymce, symfony-1.4

I need to use a HTML editor for my symfony project . Therefore I have used tinyMCE Editor with
 sfFormExtraPlugin .

These are the steps I have followed

- `php symfony plugin:install sfFormExtraPlugin`
- download the latest tinyMCE and add the tiny_MCE directory into `web/js`
- and use it inside widgets `'text' =>  new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(array()),`

But when I saving values it both diplays and saving inside db with html tags... how can I stop this ?

OR is there any other way to use HTML editor with symfony ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, that's the purpose of TinyMCE: provide a user friendly interface to built rich text. Then it saves the html into your database and you won't have to parse it again when you will have to show the content.

But if you want to use a different approach, you can use [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (used in many project like Github or even here). There are different plugin to achieve markdown integration:

- https://github.com/jmather/majaxMarkdownPlugin
- http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfWmdPlugin
- https://github.com/KnpLabs/knpMarkdownPlugin

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to save HTML tags, why do you use a sfWidgetFormTextAreTinyMCE?!
Just use a text area...

Comment: no , the thing it doesnt matter if it save with HTML tags in db, but when i try display those data in template also it give me with tags ... Anyway i fixed it using  html_entity_decode function :)

Answer (score -1):

```
sfOutputEscaper::unescape("Escaped Text");
```